# Problem in connecting to Berkely DB from java

Tags: java

i have download & install Berkeley DB 5.1.25.msi Windows installer from oracle.com 
then after i have created table in berkeley DB using following code

```
c:\Program>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\Berkeley DB 11gR2 5.1.25\bin\dbsql" Emp.db
Berkeley DB 11g Release 2, library version
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
dbsql> create table student(sno int,sname varchar(10));
dbsql> insert into student values(1.'abc');
dbsql>select * from student;
1|dhananjay
```

how can perform Database operation through java

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't a JDBC driver available.

If you're wondering why there isn't a JDBC driver, the short answer is that Berkeley DB isn't a relational database.

Take a look at this link: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/08/24/sleepy.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no JDBC driver for Berkeley DB. If you need a simple database for Java, try [H2](http://www.h2database.com/).